# Chrome Extension Content Script isn't functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a very simple program for netflix that has a couple thousand users. Every once in a while, I'll receive a review with a 1-star rating with the comment, "it doesn't work". My content script is just this:

background.js:

```
setInterval(function(){try{document.getElementsByClassName("button continue-playing")[0].click()}catch(e){}}, 33);
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Netflix Pause Removal",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "Remove the pause between netflix episodes",
  "content_scripts": [{
  "matches":["http://www.netflix.com/*"],
  "js":["background.js"]
  }]
}
```

While I have thousands of happy users, every once in a while I will have a single user say that it doesn't work: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netflix-pause-removal/mfekcpndbpdgjjfahekhncdfegkhbghg/reviews

What are the possibilities that would make the application not work?

Comment: maybe they have JS disabled.. honestly though there is a million things that could affect it

Comment: Right, but at that point I don't think that Netflix would work either.

Comment: Try changing `http://www.netflix.com/*` to `*://www.netflix.com/*` (* is http and https).